# Enviar a post sin salir de la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql-server

En una tabla imprimo los siguientes resultados de una consulta SQL Server

```
    <td role="gridcell"><span style="color: #ff0000"><strong><?php echo $resultado ?></strong></span></td> 
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Fecha'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Maquina'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo utf8_encode ($maquina['Clie_nombre']);?></td>
    <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['N_Orden']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Linea']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell" > <a target="_blank" href="https://clientes.ealbeniz.com/clientes/images/<?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art'];?>.pdf"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art']; ?></a></td>
    <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo utf8_encode( $maquina['OF_Descripcion']); ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Cant'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Metros']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['OF_Tipo_Papel'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Tip_stamp']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Ava_stamp'];?></td>
   <td role="gridcell" <?php echo ($maquina['repetido']) ? 'style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $maquina['Mag']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Troq']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Num_Tintas'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $resultado2 ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color2'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color3']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color4']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color5']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color6']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color7'];?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color8']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['tIMER']; ?></td>
    <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['ESTADO'];?></td>
```

Me gustaría poder editar el campo **$resultado** y **Maquina**.

Actualmente envío los datos a otro php (donde esta el update sql) mediante un post **POST** (enviando mediante input el dato **$resultado** y **Maquina** (que son los que edito) y **NOrden** (que es el identificador)) de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">

<tbody role="rowgroup"><tr data-uid="0bc4355b-a2b7-4cf6-9701-192e77ce6d1d" role="row">


           <td role="gridcell"> <span style="color: #ff0000"> <input type="text" name="Orden" id="Orden" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($maquina['Orden'])){echo $resultado;}?>" /></td> 

            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Fecha'];?></td>
           <td role="gridcell">  <input type="text" name="Maquina" id="Maquina" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($maquina['Maquina'])){echo $maquina['Maquina'];}?>" /></td>

            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo utf8_encode ($maquina['Clie_nombre']);?></td>

            <td role="gridcell"> <input type="text" name="NOrden" id="NOrden" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($maquina['N_Orden'])){echo $maquina['N_Orden'];}?>" /><button type="submit" style="width:5px; height:5px; background-color:white;border: 0 ;" class="btn btn-success"></button></td></form></td>


            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Linea']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" > <a target="_blank" href="https://clientes.ealbeniz.com/clientes/images/<?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art'];?>.pdf"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art']; ?></a></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo utf8_encode( $maquina['OF_Descripcion']); ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Cant'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Metros']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['OF_Tipo_Papel'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Tip_stamp']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Ava_stamp'];?></td>
           <td role="gridcell" <?php echo ($maquina['repetido']) ? 'style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $maquina['Mag']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Troq']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Num_Tintas'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $resultado2 ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color2'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color3']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color4']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color5']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color6']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color7'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color8']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['tIMER']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['ESTADO'];?></td>
        </tr>
```

Me funciona bien, pero es muy lento ya que si quiero editar varias filas, tengo que ir una por una.

¿Como podría editar los datos de varias filas a la vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, una de ella es utilizar jQuery/ajax, que cuando le dieses a editar fila, te saliese un input donde rellenar (O puedes hacerlo directamente visible), y luego un botón de guardado. Esto haría una petición mediante ajax o jquery a otra ruta php, donde haría el guardado a tu base de datos. Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('guardar').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const target = event.target;
  const parent = target.closest('tr');
  const rowId = parent.getAttribute('data-id');
  
  const campo1 = parent.querySelector('input[name="campo1"]').value;
  const campo2 = parent.querySelector('input[name="campo2"]').value;
  
  const data = {
    idFila: rowId, 
    campo1: campo1, 
    campo2: campo2
  };
  
  console.log(data);
  
  // Petición ajax para guardado
});
```

```html
<table width="100%" style="text-align:left">
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Resultado</th>
  <th>Maquina</th>
</tr>
<tr data-id="1">
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="campo1" value="Res1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="campo2" value="Maquina1"></td>
  <td>
    <!-- <input id="editar" type="button" value="Editar"/> -->
    <input id="guardar" type="button" value="Guardar"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="2">
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="campo1" value="Res2"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="campo2" value="Maquina2"></td>
  <td>
    <!-- <input id="editar" type="button" value="Editar"/> -->
    <input id="guardar" type="button" value="Guardar"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

La otra opción, con php, es utilizar un array de filas, con sus modificaciones:

```
$data = array(
    array('resultado' => 'res1', 'maquina' => 'maquina1'),
    array('resultado' => 'res2', 'maquina' => 'maquina2')
);
```

Y luego, en la ruta que hacer las consultas sql vas actualizando cada fila.